# Marker position in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, markers, tooltip

I use 2 markers : Icon and Tooltip.
The problem is that given the sames Lon & Lat they are not at the same position.
The Icon position is right, the tooltip position not.
This is my js code for the 2 markers

```
//Tooltip
var marker = new L.marker([getUrlParameter("Lat0"), getUrlParameter("Lon0")], {
  opacity: 0,
});
marker.bindTooltip(getUrlParameter("D0") + "km", {
  permanent: true,
  offset: [0, 0],
});
marker.addTo(map);
// Icon
var Marker = L.icon({
  iconUrl: "Point.png",

  iconSize: [27, 32], // size of the icon
  iconAnchor: [13, 32], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  popupAnchor: [0, -30], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var Lon = getUrlParameter("Lon");
var Lat = getUrlParameter("Lat");
var starts = new L.LayerGroup();
L.marker([Lat, Lon], { icon: Marker })
  .bindPopup(Lat + "<br>" + Lon)
  .addTo(starts);
```

and the result : the tooltip is on the left or on the right depending on the point position on the screen but shifted in both cases (Lat and Lon are the sames)

[image] [image]

Edit : the tooltip is binded to the L.marker.
When the marker is on the right of the middle of the screen the tooltip is on the left of the marker (last sample) by 15 pixels (and 25 pixels above), so I've set an offset of [15,25], it's now all right. But When the marker is on the left of the middle of the screen the tooltip is on the right of the marker (before last sample) by 15 pixels (and 25 pixels above), so with an offset of [15,25] it is 30 pixels to the right ! The Xoffset should be +15 or -15 depending on its position on the screen : how to do that ?
[image]

Comment: See https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#icon-tooltipanchor

Comment: tooltipAnchor is the coordinates of the point from which tooltips will "open", relative to the icon anchor.
I don't have any Icon associated to the tooltip.
The problem is that an Icon displays exactly at the point LatLon.
A Tooltip (alone) does not.

Comment: Your tooltip is not "alone": it is bound to the marker, and therefore linked to a icon.

Comment: OK right : the tooltip is binded to the L.marker

Comment: When the marker is on the right of the middle of the screen the tooltip is on the left of the marker (last sample) by 15 pixels (and 25 pixels above), so I've set an offset of [15,25], it's now all right. But When the marker is on the left of the middle of the screen the tooltip is on the right of the marker (before last sample) by 15 pixels (and 25 pixels above), so with an offset of [15,25] it is 30 pixels to the right ! The Xoffset should be +15 or -15 depending on its position on the screen : how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing, where tooltip offset has to be different, depending on left or right position of tooltip, is necessary in older versions of Leaflet. Fer example, I tried v1.5.4 and it still behaves that way.

If you have to use older version, there are two possible solutions. Since your tooltips are permanent, you can give them static `'right'` alignment and then offset is also static:

```
marker.bindTooltip('This is my tooltip', {direction: 'right', offset: [-15, 25], permanent: true});
```

If you want tooltips left and right aligned, depending on the initial position, you can do that with checking initial position of marker and accordingly assign the tooltip:

```
function createCustomTooltip(marker, tooltipTxt) {
  var container = map.getContainer();
  var point = map.latLngToContainerPoint(marker.getLatLng());
  if (point.x > (container.clientWidth / 2)) {
    var side = 'left';
    var offsetX = 15;
    }
  else {
    var side = 'right';
    var offsetX = -15;
  }
  marker.bindTooltip(tooltipTxt, {direction: side, offset: [offsetX, 25], permanent: true});
}

createCustomTooltip(myMarker, 'This is my tooltip');
```

If you use the latest Leaflet version 1.7.1, you don't have to worry about tooltip position any more, offset should always be negative:

```
marker.bindTooltip('This is my tooltip', {offset: [-15, 25], permanent: true});
```

Comment: This is not a solution because I want the tooltips to be permanent.
Is it possible to reach this using someting else than a tooltip ?
I just want "stickers" attached at Lat/Lng points.

Comment: Tooltip created with this solution is permanent in the sense that once you define/create tooltip with the `createCustomTooltip`, this tooltip will work all the time. If you can find better solution, go ahead.

Comment: I don't understand : on one hand you wrote "Tooltip with desired position is dynamically created and displayed on marker mouseover" and now "Tooltip created with this solution is permanent"; does the tooltip appear permanently or only at mouseover ?
I would like permanent labels whether they are in the form of tooltips or whatever.

Comment: I've tried your function `var marker = new L.marker([Lat,Lon], { opacity: 0 }); 
createCustomTooltip(marker, Dist+"km<br>"+Time),
marker.addTo(map);` 
I don't see any tooltip.

Comment: See working JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/d1m3ht2u/. For some strange reason (probably due to JSFiddle environment), offset `offsetX` has to be negative for both left and right side.

Comment: I see your markers, mouseover reveals the tooltip.
See my maps here https://www.rudyv.be/PilotePrive/Agenda.php (click on a small France map to open a map) : I don't have any visible marker so If I use your code I don't know that I should walk the mouse to reveal the tooltip, that's the reason why the tooltips are permanent.

Comment: In your question you are talking about markers, now suddenly you don't have any marker. This is different question then, so it should be posted as a new question.

Comment: I use visible Icon markers on one hand `var Marker = L.icon ...` and on the other hand invisible markers in order to bind permanent tooltips to them `var Marker = new L.marker ...`; the problem is that the tooltip is not at the marker LatLng position, it depends on the marker position on the screen.

Comment: Of course you don't know where the tooltip shold be, so I gave you an exemple with a visible marker (last picture initial post) to show you that when the marker is on the right of the screen the associated tooltip is well positionned while when the marker is on the left the tooltip is too much on the right.

Comment: Try using the latest Leaflet 1.7.1.

Comment: Good Idea : how can I know the version I'm using ?

Comment: From Leaflet JS include. In the example from your comment above it's `<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>`, so version is 1.3.4

Comment: See completely revised answer.

Comment: I've downloaded 1.7.1 : it works better but not as accurate as expected, example https://www.rudyv.be/OSM/Map2.html?map=PilotePrive/Itineraires/210420.xml&D0=40&T0=16&Lat0=50.6739&Lon0=3.622

Comment: When the tooltip is on the right it is ok, but when it is on the left it is too far left, same example offset: [-15, 25] https://www.rudyv.be/Temp/Map.jpg